# Angle between 3 point

Tags: java, geometry

I gone thouth the url https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361412/finding-the-angle-between-three-points
and wrote a simple code as follows. Not sure how can I test it.

```
 double x1 = 2, x2 = 3, x3= 4;
     double y1 = 200, y2 = 215, y3= 225; 

     double l1x = x2 - x1;
     double l1y = y2 - y1;

     double l1xSQR = l1x * l1x;
     double l1ySQR = l1y * l1y;

     double l1SQRT = Math.sqrt(l1xSQR + l1ySQR);

     double l2x = x3 - x2;
     double l2y = y3 - y2;

     double l2xSQR = l2x * l2x;
     double l2ySQR = l2y * l2y;

     double l2SQRT = Math.sqrt(l2xSQR + l2ySQR);

     System.out.println(Math.abs(Math.cos(((l1x * l2x) + (l1y * l2y))/(l1SQRT*l2SQRT))));
```

Is this correct way to find the angle between 3 point in 2D.

Comment: You test this code in the same way that you test other code - come up with examples, solve them manually, feed them to your code, and see if the code behaves.

Comment: Like @dasblinkenlight said, feed some numbers to your code and come up with a hypothesis of how the code should play out according to what numbers you fed it. You could also print your variables throughout the process of the code to see how the values are changing or even use alerts to see if the code is making it to a certain point in the program

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
((l1x * l2x) + (l1y * l2y))/(l1SQRT*l2SQRT)
```

is already the cosine of the desired angle, so you should write

```
Math.acos(((l1x * l2x) + (l1y * l2y))/(l1SQRT*l2SQRT))
```

to get the angle in radians. Or

```
Math.acos(((l1x * l2x) + (l1y * l2y))/(l1SQRT*l2SQRT)) * 180.0 / Math.PI
```

if you need it in degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Can be better as regards accuracy and generality to use

```
atan2(D20x * D10y - D20y * D10x, D20x * D10x + D20y * D10y).
```

Also

```
atan2(D20y, D20x) - atan2(D10y, D10x),
```

which takes two `atan` calls.